# Using ufw on OpenVZ-based VPSes

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvz, ufw

I'm facing with a problem to set up ufw on Ubuntu 12.04 running on an OpenVZ-based VPS. I know there is limitations for ufw. I googled a bunch of articles how to resolve the issue (like: http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/how-to-use-ufw-in-openvz-templates/).

But if I'm trying to apply those approaches I'm stuck that

> ufw-init force-reload

just skips:

```
# ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
ERROR: problem running ufw-init

# /lib/ufw/ufw-init force-reload
Skipping  (not enabled)
```

I cannot figure out whether it's possible to use ufw? If not, should I be dealing with iptables?